# How to pop a UIViewControllerRepresentable from a SwiftUI navigation stack programmatically

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview, navigationlink, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

Here is my SwiftUI setup:

I have a SwiftUI view (called MapSearchView) that has a NavigationView that contains a NavigationLink.

```
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section (header: Text("Location")){
                    NavigationLink (locationString, destination: GooglePlacesViewController(mapTools: $mapTools))
                }...
```

The NavigationLink's destination is a UIViewControllerRepresentable which wraps a GooglePlacesViewController. When I am done with my GooglePlaces search (either because I made a selection or I cancelled the search), I want to programmatically pop back to the MapSearchView.

I have tried adding the following in the UIViewControllerRepresentable (GooglePlacesViewController):

```
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var popToPrevious : Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if popToPrevious == true {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

and setting the popToPrevious to true in my Coordinator using

```
parent.popToPrevious = true
```

It does get called, but does nothing.

I have also tried in the Coordinator to call

`view.viewController().navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)`

(viewController() is an extension that gets the viewController for any view)

This also does nothing.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create Coordinator with owner view (ie. your representable), then try to call directly when needed

```
ownerView.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

Comment: Thank you. I must have been asleep when I was working on this because that is such the obvious answer and I have done it several times before! Thank you once again for your help!